# Node js linter that follows requires

Tags: node.js, jslint, lint

There are many tools to lint node.js files, but I can't seem to find one that would recursively go through require's. Ex -

```
var otherModule = require('./otherModule.js');
console.log(otherModule.func1());
```

Is there an app that can raise an error if func1 is not defined in otherModule?

Comment: Please consider adding more content to your question if you hope to get a good answer. Start with telling us what you've tried?

Answer (score 2):

Typically you do not want a linter to follow requires since you do not control the source of modules you have not written yourself.

Focus on linting your own code, both at the top level `index.js` and any included libraries of your own design `./lib`.

UPDATED

I know of no tool that guarantees you are not misusing a module by calling functions or methods it does not provide. It is up to the programmer to assure that she abides by the module's contract.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to work for modules. What if I am trying to call a function in a class defined in the same file? Is there some reason that the class can't be parsed?

Comment: Have you run a lint on the file? If you have a class with methods, you "new" an instance of that class and you cannot access any of its methods, you more than likely have some problem with the definition of your class.